# Waterproof Bathroom wall

Tags: bathroom

I need to waterproof my bathroom wall

The tiles only go half way up and when taking a shower - 
There’s usually quite a lot of splash back

I was wondering if I could just put stick back plastic on the surface closest to the shower head ?

If your from the uk it’s the type of stuff you were made to put on your work books

Comment: So, this isn't simply a bathroom wall, it's actually a wall inside a shower area that is exposed to significant moisture/water splash. What is the wall surface now if it is not tiled (painted plaster, painted brick, concrete, etc.)? Has this *recently* become a shower where there wasn't one before? If not, how come there has been no problem to this point in time (or has there)? How about a picture?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It’s a new house - I did t even think about it when purchasing. It’s a dot and sap plaster. Every time it gets wet - throwing cones off. Is waterproof paint a good idea ?

Comment: Well, "stick back plastic" would surely be preferable to exposed plaster, and probably more protective than any paint alone would be. Seal up the joint where plastic meets tile with caulking. The alternative would be a complete cement board & waterproofing membrane with tile over the top, much more work.

Comment: What does 'throwing cones off" mean? Yank here, just curious.

Comment: Apologies - predictive text is a nightmare. Paint comes off. I’m going to try waterproof print and see how far i get

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're talking about adhesive-coated flexible plastic that one would laminate with. My guess is that you'd have a tough time keeping it properly stuck to the wall. I'd instead recommend a rigid sheet plastic product, one with some thickness, such as this [1/16" x 4' x 8' plastic panel from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/1-16-in-x-4-ft-x-8-ft-Plastic-Panel-63003/202090190). Cut it to size, glue it in place, and caulk the edges. Should be much more durable.